# Grepping the hostname which returns duplicate entries

Tags: linux

I have a host and host file is maintained as below

```
10.150.23.04    abc.xyz.com abc
10.150.23.04    abc.xyz.com abc
```

I have deliberately put dual entries to work on the logic if the host file has duplicate entries for the host.

The command hostname is returning me the value `abc` The hostname -i is returning me the ip value but twice i.e. hostname -i outputs to `10.150.23.04 10.150.23.04`

As a result when I run the below to filter the host file for the duplicate entries :

```sh
grep -v '^\s*#' /etc/hosts | grep $(hostname) | grep $(hostname -i)
```

It gives me the output

```
grep: 10.150.23.04: No such file or directory
```

What should be done for the proper grep output of filtering out the duplicate entries?

Tried doing this as input

```sh
grep -v '^\s*#' /etc/hosts | grep $(hostname) | grep $(hostname -i)
```

The expected output has to be as below :

```
10.150.23.04    abc.xyz.com abc
10.150.23.04    abc.xyz.com abc
```

Comment: Unclear : It seems like you are looking for `grep "$(hostname)" /etc/hosts`.

Comment: @harrymc- im trying to grep the ip from the duplicate  hostname entries .it ends up with the error  grep: 10.150.23.04: No such file or directory

Comment: Your "expected output" is just lines from the `hosts` file. My comment is that either you require another output than in your question, or you just need to grep the file.